# SQL SELECT TOP N per ID, per Time, per Group

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm really having a hard time to write the stored procedure.
Here is the case.

I'm joining several tables in a stored procedure and store it in a temporary table.
Below is the illustration of the result given by the stored procedure :

```
CLIENT        Request     Month   Total

Client A      A           1       1
Client A      B           1       3
Client A      C           1       9
Client A      D           1       4 
Client A      E           1       6

Client A      A           2       6
Client A      B           2       9
Client A      C           2       1
Client A      D           2       3 
Client A      E           2       2

Client B      A           1       3
Client B      B           1       7
Client B      C           1       9
Client B      D           1       8 
Client B      E           1       4

Client B      A           2       5
Client B      B           2       8
Client B      C           2       1
Client B      D           2       1 
Client B      E           2       3
```

My question is, how can I get the TOP N (eg : top 3) for each clients per month based on the highest total request.

I'm going to use the stored procudere for a chart in Reporting Service, i'm also having a hard time using the filter function in the chart, so i think there's any possibilities to filter it at the first place from the sql query.

I hope me and the illustration above explained the problem clearly. I really appreciate every responses from you.
Thanks so much before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TABLE Table
(
    CLIENT varchar(100),Request varchar(10),[Month] int,Total int
)

Insert into @Table

Select 'Client A','A',1,1 UNION ALL
Select 'Client A','B',1,3 UNION ALL
Select 'Client A','C',1,9 UNION ALL
Select 'Client A','D',1,4 UNION ALL
Select 'Client A','E',1,6 UNION ALL
Select 'Client A','A',2,6 UNION ALL
Select 'Client A','B',2,9 UNION ALL
Select 'Client A','C',2,1 UNION ALL
Select 'Client A','D',2,3 UNION ALL
Select 'Client A','E',2,2 UNION ALL
Select 'Client B','A',1,3 UNION ALL
Select 'Client B','B',1,7 UNION ALL
Select 'Client B','C',1,9 UNION ALL
Select 'Client B','D',1,8 UNION ALL
Select 'Client B','E',1,4 UNION ALL
Select 'Client B','A',2,5 UNION ALL
Select 'Client B','B',2,8 UNION ALL
Select 'Client B','C',2,1 UNION ALL
Select 'Client B','D',2,1 UNION ALL
Select 'Client B','E',2,3

Declare @Top int
Set @Top=2

;with CTE AS
(
    SELECT CLIENT,Request,[Month],Total,
    --month wise top record based on total request 
    ROW_NUMBER()Over(Partition by CLIENT,[Month] Order by  Total Desc) AS RN
    FROM @Table
)
Select *
From CTE
where rn<=@Top
Order by CLIENT
```

Comment: thx for the response dude. it really helps.
the ROW_NUMBER() thingy is the key which is also suggested by Ovidiu Pacurar.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `GROUPBY` clause  to find out the counts made by each client, and then use `HAVING` to filter out the data of created `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [row_number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) with **partition by** CLIENT and **order by** TOTAL DESC

Comment: i've tried what you told above, but it only returned the row number, how could i use the row number so that the result shows the top 3. thx for the response

Comment: thx for the solution dude, i've figured out how to use the row number to get the result that i wanted.